List or report on number of smart groups a contact is in
Is there anyway (using SearchKit or any other way) I can display a list of contacts who are in more than 1 smart group? I have 160,000 contacts and I need to make sure that my contacts are only in 1 smart group. I cannot see a way to do this.

How many smart groups do you have? If 2, then it'd be easy enough to search for contacts in both groups.
If > 2... that's trickier.

I have 24 Smart Groups, with about 9000 contacts spread across these groups. I’m certain I’ve got contacts in more than 1 smart group, which I don’t want.

I think you'd need to write a bit of sql for that. Basically you need to trigger all smart groups to rebuild, then SELECT contact_id FROM civicrm_group_contact_cache WHERE COUNT(contact_id) > 1 GROUP_BY contact_id;

I couldn't get  ">1" to work, but I did get this to work:
SELECT contact_id, group_id,COUNT(contact_id) FROM civicrm_group_contact_cache GROUP BY contact_id ORDER BY COUNT(contact_id) DESC;
which showed me the contacts in more than 1 smart group, so then it was easy to track down which smart group had the same filter in twice. Thanks for pointing the way @Coleman

Cool. Just FYI that cache gets cleared regularly so you can't assume it always contains all contacts for every group.
